# MergeSort problems parameters

Tags: java, mergesort

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array; 

public class Sorting {
public static void mergeSort(CompareInt[] arr) {

   for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
        System.out.println("Initial Arr element:"+arr[i].val);
        } 
    CompareInt[] arrAux;
    arrAux = new CompareInt[arr.length];
    mergeS(arr,0,arr.length-1,arrAux);       
}

public static void mergeS(CompareInt[] arr,int startI,int endI,CompareInt[] arrAux){
    //System.out.println("StartIndex:"+startI+" EndIndex:"+endI);
    if(endI-startI<=0)
        return;

    int mid = (startI+endI)/2;
   // System.out.println("Midpoint value:"+mid);

    mergeS(arr,startI,mid);
    mergeS(arr,mid+1,endI);

  //  System.out.println("Inside mergeS");
  //  System.out.println("StartIndex:"+startI+" EndIndex:"+endI+" Midpoint value:"+mid);
 //   System.out.println("Arr length:"+arr.length);

    arrAux = merge(arr,mid);

    for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
        arr[i]=arrAux[i];
        System.out.println("Arr element:"+arr[i].val);
        }
}


public static CompareInt[] merge(CompareInt[] arr,int midpoint){
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
int n1 = arr.length-midpoint;
int n2 = arr.length-n1;

//System.out.println("Midpoint value inside merge:"+midpoint);
//System.out.println("N1:"+n1+" N2:"+n2);

CompareInt[] L;
CompareInt[] R;
CompareInt[] resA;
L = new CompareInt[n1];
R = new CompareInt[n2];
resA = new CompareInt[n1+n2];


for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
    L[i]=arr[i];
  // System.out.println("Inside Left loop"+i);
  // System.out.println(L[i].val);
    }

for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
    R[j]=arr[midpoint+j+1];
   // System.out.println("Inside Right loop "+j);
   // System.out.println(R[j].val);
}

i=0;
j=0;
k=0;

while(i<n1 && j<n2){
    if(L[i].compareTo(R[j])<=0){
        resA[k]=L[i];
       // System.out.println(resA[i].val);
        i++;
    }
    else{
        resA[k]=R[j];
       // System.out.println(resA[j].val);
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

while(i<n1){
    resA[k]=L[i];
    //System.out.println(resA[k].val);
    i++;
    k++;
}

while(j<n2){
    resA[k]=R[j];
    //System.out.println(resA[k].val);
    j++;
    k++;
}

 return resA;  
}
}
```

I am getting actual and formal argument lists differ in length at line mereS(..)
How do I solve this error and is there any way to run with different number of arguments in actual and formal parameters.

This is how [Pseudo code](https://courses.edx.org/assets/courseware/v1/04f4c5d2a35cd63cf267aebe9e72ef84/asset-v1:PennX+SD3x+3T2019+type@asset+block/Week1_SlideDeck_v2.pdf) is given ..
Modifications in pseudo code:
if (hi - lo <= 0)", not "if (hi - lo <= 1)".
aux <- merge(A[lo:mid], A[mid+1:hi])

Comment: The declaration of `mergeS()` takes 4 arguments, but you are only passing in 3 when you call it. Looks like `arrAux` is missing.

Comment: yes arrAux is missing but even after adding arrAux in mergeS() I am not getting sorted array.

Comment: What are you getting, specifically?

Comment: I think your `L` and `R` sizes may be reversed. Shouldn't it be `int n2 = arr.length-midpoint;` instead of `n1`?

Comment: No I have tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will sort out your problem :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7};

    System.out.println("\nSorted array");
    for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
        System.out.println("Initial Arr element:"+arr[i]);
    }

    mergeS(arr, 0, arr.length-1);

    System.out.println("\nSorted array");
    for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
        System.out.println("Sorted Arr element:"+arr[i]);
    }
}


public static void mergeS(int[] arr,int startI,int endI){
    //System.out.println("StartIndex:"+startI+" EndIndex:"+endI)

    if (startI< endI)
    {
        // Find the middle point
        int m = (startI+endI)/2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        mergeS(arr,startI, m);
        mergeS(arr , m+1, endI);

        // Merge the sorted halves
        merge(arr, startI,m, endI);
    }
}


public static void merge(int arr[], int startI, int midpoint, int endI){
    // Find sizes of two subarrays to be merged
    int n1 = midpoint - startI + 1;
    int n2 = endI - midpoint;

    /* Create temp arrays */
    int L[] = new int [n1];
    int R[] = new int [n2];

    /*Copy data to temp arrays*/
    for (int i=0; i<n1; ++i)
        L[i] = arr[startI + i];
    for (int j=0; j<n2; ++j)
        R[j] = arr[midpoint + 1+ j];


    /* Merge the temp arrays */

    // Initial indexes of first and second subarrays
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    // Initial index of merged subarry array
    int k = startI;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy remaining elements of L[] if any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy remaining elements of R[] if any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```